# Correct callbacks for geocoder validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I hope this is not a dupe but since I haven't found a satisfying answer so far I'm gonna put my question. I'm a rails beginner so please be gentle on me ;)

For a small mapping project we're using geocoder gem. We have a model `Place` containing `:street`, `:house_number`, `:postal_code`, `:city` wrapped up as a simple string by `:address` as the virtual attribute which is being passed to geocoder. We're doing the querying using nominatim (-> OSM data). Unlike the google API nominatim returns nil if the given address does not correspond to a lat/lon pair. So far our model file looks like this

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :descriptions, :dependent => :delete_all
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :descriptions

  geocoded_by :address
  before_validation :geocode

  validates :address, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :longitude, presence: true,
                        numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 90, greater_than_or_equal_to: -90 }
  validates :latitude, presence: true,
                       numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 180, greater_than_or_equal_to: -180 }
  validates :categories, presence: true

  def address
    ["#{self.street} #{self.house_number}", self.postal_code, self.city].join(', ')
  end
end
```

Unlike most of the examples I've looked at I'm using `before_validation :geocode` because otherwise lat and lon would be nil before they become evaluated raising a validation error (not present).
So far this works for creating new places but I'm unable to modify the validation to make it work for the `update` action inside my controller. Basically I want to check if the changes applied to `address` are valid (i.e. whether the API finds a lat/lon pair to the given address). Studying the documentation i found, that i do a conditional callback like `before_validate :geocode, if: :address_changed?` but since the parameters of the update request are not available inside my model I have no clue how to check that. I'd be glad on any hint!

edit:

Accepted answer below is right, wasn't working instantly because inside my controller I was using `update` instead of `update_attributes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model doesn't need to know the parameters to update the request. You can check if the address changed by checking if any of the columns which make up your address have changed. Since `address` isn't a column, you'll need to define `address_changed?` like so:

```
before_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?

def address_changed?
  street_changed? || house_number_changed? || postal_code_changed? || city_changed?
end
```

Note that `street`, `house_number`, `city` and `postal_code` will all need to be columns in order for the above to work.

Comment: This does not work. I assume `*_changed?` are helper methods? Where do they come from?

Comment: It's not a helper method, it's defined by Rails. The convention is that an instance method `<column_name>_changed?` is defined for every column in your model and will return true if that column value is either being set for the first time, or has changed since it was last persisted.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In the console I can test these methods, they work. Nevertheless they don't work in the context of the proposed `address_changed?` method used in the conditional callback. I still can `update` malformed entries without them getting geocoded (which would raise an error). Any idea?

Comment: Ok, I'm approaching the problem... debugging the `update` method in my controller reveals, that - although params are passed correctly and changes have been applied - `*_changed?` returns `false`...

Comment: Are you still using `before_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?`?

Comment: Yep and it seems I found the error. Within my controller I was using `update` instead of `update_attributes`. Now everything works fine, although I don't quite understand why... Gonn update the question